# Remove Last Character if its a number

Tags: mysql

Basically, I have a database with over 1 million records, where duplicated values are deemed as duplicates and have a number at the end of the record.

Is there an SQL statement that selects value if the last character is a number?

```
select RIGHT('abcdeffff',1)
```

I need a mySQL version, that gets the last character as so but with if statement checking if it's an integer?

Comment: Where RIGHT('abcdeffff',1) REGEXP ('[0-9]')

Comment: @Dobbins Worked a treat thanks! If you pop that answer into the answers ill accept - cheers!

Comment: Very welcome!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using REGEXP.

```
 Where RIGHT('abcdeffff',1) REGEXP ('[0-9]')
```